# Netherlands checklist, document proving caregiver in your original country

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, netherlands

We applied for a Netherlands visa, but our kids will stay in our country

If we attach their school registration form would it be a good document?

Comment: Is it a full-time boarding school, i.e. will they be caring for your children full-time? (I've never heard of visas requiring proof that you're not neglecting your children though.)

Comment: @Rup, I believe the school registration is proving that they have the idea to come back.....

Comment: @Rup, no they will stay wz mum but registration is proving we will come back for them . just i ask .children is under caregiver situation?

Comment: OK, sorry for the confusion. To me, "caregiver" means who will be looking after them, rather than proof of your ties to your home country. Was this a word on the form? They may have meant someone who looks after elderly relatives or ill partners etc. rather than children - that's when the word is normally used.

Comment: oh.no problem .thanx for ur reply...